# Tutorial on creating publication quality documents in Mathematica?

Tags: formatting, publishing

Are there books or tutorials that walk one through creating a professional publication quality notebook?

For example, I would like to create a two column article using an IEEE format. Is this possible?

Cross-link to [Wolfram Community post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1003364)

Related [Math Stack Exchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684132/latex-tex-vs-mathematica-for-typesetting/)

Comment: Please don't. It will save you a lot of headaches. Yes, you can create nice documents with reference in Mathematica, but it is just not comparable to e.g. LaTeX documents. Why don't you go to [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/project) and create an IEEE article and start writing?

Comment: Reluctantly, I have to agree that this will be more headache than it is worth. What I do is write up in Mathematica using one of the article styles, then Save as > LaTeX and do further processing in a text editor, after adding the appropriate article class and the like. Not much fun, not as efficient as I would like. But the biggest problems tend to be getting formatting just right during the text editing.I hope some day we improve the save-to-TeX end of this (possibly via style sheets that are journal-aware).

Comment: It certainly is possible to create beautiful documents with _Mathematica_ - we did our book in this manner, which also has the huge advantage of having live electronic versions of the same document/book that are interactive and identical to the printed version. BUT ... two column text is not something that Mma can practically do (at least the last time I tried, other than a manual grid box), and page layouts are a pain.

Comment: Thanks all - this is useful information.  I looked at some seminar material from an individual who authored a book using Mathematica.  This did not fully answer the mail on workflow.  In other words, what is the process of making the inevitable edits to creating a file that is acceptable to the publisher?  There is also a practical problem of staff writers working with Mathematica.  Most will not know how to write Mathematica code required to make publication quality tables.  The AuthoringTools package is useful - but dated and just not there. I agree Save as > LaTex is the best way.

Comment: Isn't not possible yet... perhaps WRI will release some newer book making toolset eventually?

Comment: @Daniel The TeX conversion is very much in need of updating. It should support the newly added common symbols, like the `<|` in associations. Instead of producing `\unicode{...}` when it doesn't know the correct LaTeX command, it should produce something which is easier to use directly, e.g. `\symbol{"...}` ([like here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32514/6302)).  (I did suggest this to support before.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135572/2-column-documents-in-mathematica/7138184#7138184

Comment: Related: [Where is the “Insert > Citation> Bibliographical Reference” Command?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18835/245), [Export Plots to LaTeX](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5132/245), [Using Mathematica in Conjunction with LyX. Path Issues?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42795/245). Use Lyx!

Comment: I have been asking for material of this sort for years and years. There's bits and pieces strewn all across the internet, but Wolfram has never put some consistent and *non-trivial* sets of material together to help. There are a few examples of nice articles and even entire textbooks that demonstrate what can be done. However, the people who created these had brought years of experience *plus* several man-years of work in those specific projects to the table to make it happen. Without that kind of an investment it's pretty much impossible to do what you and I and many others would love to do.

Comment: As an aside, apart from the above, Mathematica's typesetting quality is, of course, "make-your-skin-crawl" atrocious when compared to a true typesetting system such as LaTeX. So, "professional publication quality" is never going to happen in any case; not in the foreseeable future, anyway.

Comment: All comments make me terribly sad. This should really be Prio #1 within WRI.